# Angular js: using a directive from another directive (chaining)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to compile a directive in another directive in angularjs (directive chaining?) and apparently I can't come up with a proper way to do this.

The directive I'm trying to write is an extension of the [angularui-bootstrap typeahead](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). The goal is being able to select multiple elements throught the typeahead.

What I've come up till now is the following code:

tagSelector.js:

```
angular.module('xxxTagSelector', [])
    .directive('xxxTagSelector',
            function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: 'tagSelector.html',
                    scope: {
                        selectExpr: '@',
                        editable: '@',
                        onSelect: '@'
                    }
                    }
                };
            });
```

tagSelector.html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected"
           typeahead="{{selectExpr}}" 
           typeahead-editable="{{editable}}" typeahead-on-select="{{onSelect}}" 
           placeholder="Tag Search">
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <!-- It will display selected elements -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

main.html

```
<xxx-tag-selector select-expr="tag as tag.label for tag in tags | filter:{label: $viewValue} | limitTo:8"
                                  id="tags" editable="true" on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" >
</xxx-tag-selector>
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the select-expr, editable and on-select parameters and use them in the tagSelector without any kind processing. Reading them like strings seems not to be the right path unfortunately.

Do you have any idea?

Can you point me towards some good documentation on the subject? The best thing I've down till now to understand what to do is reading suorce code.

Thank you

Comment: I would start by disregarding the `ng-model` on input, and create another scope array that you push to from `onSelect()`. Click on icon in tag to remove from that array. Start simple by just using your `xxxTagSelector` to compile your template and store the array. Then add features once you get that figured out

Comment: You are right. First of all I'll edit the answer by removing those unnecessary bits. I included them to make my intentions more clear but they are not necessary at all.

Comment: actually you will need the `ng-model` from input, that's what you would push to your tags array

Comment: Yeah I know, but I think it's part of the logic behind of what I'm trying to build and it's not directly part of the problem. Adding the ng-model part and everything else when the directive chaining is working is something I can do.